# GitHub pages site does not work, but will work locally with Jekyll

Tags: html, css, jekyll, config, github-pages

https://github.com/constellation-creator/constellation-creator.github.io

I get a 404 page cannot be found error whenever I try to load my page using GitHub pages. However if I run it locally using Jekyll serve it works fine with no errors. I already configured the Gemfile and the _config.yml file. I am not sure what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I took all files out of the main folder they were in and that seemed to work. A root folder seemed to confuse github pages, sub folders were ok